# Shortest/Best way to do this list task in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm learning Python. I'd like to do the following task:

- Input: a list: e.g., `['a', 'b', 'c']`
- Output: a single string that concatenate all elements in the list, while each element is modifed in the same way for all elements.

For example, I'd like to add `"-temp"` to each element in the list. So, the output would be:

`"a-temp b-temp c-temp"`

Of couse, I can write C/C++ style. But, is there more elegant or interesting way in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> ' '.join( x+'-temp' for x in ['a', 'b', 'c'] )
'a-temp b-temp c-temp'
```

Comment: I believe you need to surround your list comprehension with [brackets]

Comment: no they are only needed if the comprehension isn't the only argument and using [] around one makes it construct a list while () has it create a iterator the () is only needed if it is syntactically called for

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions are your friend:

```
lst =  ['a', 'b', 'c']
print ' '.join(['%s-temp' % item for item in lst])
```

Comment: `[]` are unnecessary, since you can just use the generator comprehension and pass that to the join call.

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehensions when you need to access and use each element of a list. Example:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
' '.join([element + '-temp' for element in l])
```

Comment: err, why the downvote? Someone just went and downvoted everyone. What gives?

Comment: well, it was counterproductive, because I just voted you all back up. Enjoy :)

Comment: +1 to cancel downvote, this is a correct answer. (Though the `[]` are unnecessary.)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
s = " ".join(["%s-temp" % s for s in thelist])
```

That contains a list comprehension that maps the elements of `thelist` through a string interpolation, generating a new list. That is then joined with a space in between to get the final string.

Comment: Result is `'a-temp b-temp c-temp'` exactly as the the OP asked. Please explain your downvote.

Comment: +1 to cancel downvote, this is a correct answer. (Though the `[]` are not necessary in this case.)

Comment: @Amber I know, but I decided to include them since the OP is just learning so I wanted the list comprehension to be explicit. That way the OP learns the more general list comprehension as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 '-temp'.join(list)
```

I believe will do it.

---

Almost:

```
 '-temp '.join(['a','b','c'])+'-temp'
```

Comment: Nope. It wouldn't put anything after the last one.

Comment: no as `'-temp'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` that would result in `'a-tempb-tempc'`

Comment: Somewhat awkward, considering you could just do the `-temp` append inside the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function as below:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
map((lambda s: s + '-temp'), l)
```

Comment: I believe list comprehensions are the favoured pythonic way, rather than using map/filter/reduce etc.

Comment: @Josh - you're correct, comprehensions are preferred over `filter` and `map`. However, `reduce` has unique functionality that doesn't intersect with comprehensions.